# Handle exception of the Await.result from Scala Future

Tags: scala, exception, future

I have a for comprehension in Scala and I want to handle an Exception of the Await.result. The problem is that my catch shows `None.get`, but not my exception that I defined.

The exception is caught at `case e: Exception => BadRequest(s"Exception found: ${e.getMessage}")` but it is a Future. I would like to show the getMessage.

```
try {
  val futureResult = for {
    futureRackRow <- rackRepository.getById(rack.id) recoverWith {
      case e: Exception => throw RackException(s"Error on select Rack: ${e.getMessage}")
    }
    futureSeqGpuRow <- gpuRepository.getByRack(futureRackRow.get.id) recoverWith {
      case e: Exception => throw GpuException(s"Error on select Gpu's from Rack: ${e.getMessage}")
    }
  } yield (futureRackRow, futureSeqGpuRow)
  println(2)
  val result = Await.result(futureResult, 20 seconds) // The exception comes here ....

  result._1 match {
    case Some(rackRow) => ???
    case None => ???
  }
  Ok
} catch {
  case re: RackException => BadRequest(s"Rack Exception: ${re.getMessage}")
  case ge: GpuException => BadRequest(s"Gpu Exception: ${ge.getMessage}")
  case e: Exception => BadRequest(s"Exception found: ${e.getMessage}")
}
```

Comment: the code you posted does not have `Option.get` so it is unclear how you can get a `None.get` exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd assume you get the exception with `None.get` is that the `futureRackRow` is `None` here. Then before even calling getByRack it will throw an Exception for calling `.id` on it. Thus it has nothing to do with the Futures :)

Best catch it before the block, like

```
if (futureRackRow.nonEmpty) {
  ...
}
```

or if you have some default value you could use this instead of the .get.id

```
 futureRackRow.map(_.id).getOrElse(0)
```

Comment: I cannot use isEmpty inside for {} yield and throw an Exception. Everything that I write after Await.result will not be executed. My exception is inside `rackRepository.getById(rack.id)`, but the `throw RackException` is not been executed....

Comment: How do you know the exception is in `rackRepository.getById(rack.id)`? I don't think so. You need to handle the case that the Option `futureRackRow` is `None`, thus I meant to wrap your whole code with the `.isEmpty` , or use a default value if available.

Comment: I put a NonSushElementException on the end to solve this. I still cannot get the specific exception and I couldn't use isEmpty around the for{}. Here is my implementation https://github.com/felipegutierrez/crypto-miners-demo/blob/master/app/controllers/GpuController.scala#L66 If you could give to me an example of your idea it will be nice as well. Thanks

Comment: I am also wondering if it is possible to remove the `Await.result(futureResult, 20 seconds)` from my code....